# How add different css styles for date_select field?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have select list for input birthday

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, {include_blank: true, start_year: Time.now.year - 70} %>
```

I need add following css style in date_select. I cant undestand, how add different css classes? Can you help me, please?

```
<select class="form-control_medium" tabindex="-1" role="chzn_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="1">Yanuary</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
 ....................................
</select

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 150px;" title=""><a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Month</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="" tabindex="3"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `{ class: 'form-control_medium' }` to your `date_select`, something like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, {include_blank: true, start_year: Time.now.year - 70}, { class: 'form-control_medium' } %>
```

Have a look at the [docs for data_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/date_select).